# I need to extract some variables from a string in java

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have `String str="Hello $everybody$. How $are$ you $all$";`
From above string, I need to extract values `everybody`, `are`, `all` to a list. Note all the required values are started and ended with $.  How can I do it in java?

Please help.

regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\w.*?)\\$");
        String s = "Hello $everybody$. How $are$ you $all$";

        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the only answer where the regex quantifier is reluctant. All others use greedy quantifiers at the time of writing this.

Comment: I have tried with this code. It is working fine. Thank you everybody for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api)

You'll need a pattern like:

```
\$[\w]+\$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try working through this tutorial: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/ — it should help. `\$(\w+)\$` is the trick.

Comment: Don't forget to use a reluctant quantifier: `+?`

Comment: @EmilLundberg `\w` is `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, and thus doesn't match `$`, so there's no need in `?`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Matcher` class in Java.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "$(.*)$", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // Get the matching string
    String match = matcher.group();
}
```

Comment: `(.*)` will catch `$` as well, so `$one$ $two$` will be one variable — is it as expected? Additionally, `$` should probably be escaped.

Comment: Also, the quantifier should be reluctant (`*?`), not greedy.